# @RabbitListener can't connect to rabbitMQ from the same docker container

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have Spring app which works with RabbitMQ. They both suppose to work as Docker container.
When I start only RabbitMQ as Docker container, my app can work with it from the host (both from IDEA and being launched from Terminal as jar).
Also, my app can create new Queue both being launched from the host and as Docker container.
Problems start with @RabbitListener. It works from the host, but not inside Docker container.

Error log:

```
[2021-08-17 18:22:58,703] [INFO] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.connectHostPort:648] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-7] - Attempting to connect to: rabbitnet:5672
[2021-08-17 18:22:58,704] [ERROR] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary:1877] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-7] - Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitnet
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:70)

    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602)

    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2132)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2105)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2085)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueInfo(RabbitAdmin.java:407)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:391)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1890)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1871)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1192)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitnet
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1133)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1087)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectHostPort(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:651)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:616)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Here is `docker-compose.ym`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    hostname: myapphost
    networks:
      - rabbitnet
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbithost
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      - rabbitnet
networks:
  rabbitnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11 as jdkbase
FROM jdkbase

COPY target/dependency-jars /run/dependency-jars
COPY target/resources /run/resources
ADD target/myapp-1.0.0.jar /run/myapp-1.0.0.jar

CMD java -jar run/myapp-1.0.0.jar
```

Here is class and method, where the app listens to the RabbitMQ:

```
@Slf4j @Component
public class MsgRdr {
   @SneakyThrows @RabbitListener(queues = Q_INPUT)
   public void read(@Valid @Payload MyMessage message, @Headers Map<String, Object> headers) {
   log.info("Received: ");
   this.MyHandler.handleAll(message);
   }
}
```

Here is Rabbit configs:

```
@Configuration @EnableRabbit
@Import(BaseConfig.class)
public class MyRabbitConfiguration {

//THIS METHOD WORKS FINE EVERYWHERE
@Bean
public Queue myQueue(@Value(Q_INPUT) String name) {
System.out.println("==== myQueue creation ====");
Queue q = new Queue(name, true);
System.out.println("==== myQueue creation done! ====");
return q;
}

//bla-bla-bla creating factory and message template
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class BaseConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {
@Autowired private MessageHandlerMethodFactory messageHandlerMethodFactory;

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(/*...*/) {
System.out.println("=== rabbitListenerContainerFactory ===");
   SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
   factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
   factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
   factory.setPrefetchCount(1);
   factory.setContainerCustomizer(c -> 
   c.setShutdownTimeout(timeout));
   //setting other configs
   return factory;
   }
   //bla-bla other methods...
}
```

POM dependecy for rabbit:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitnet seems to be a miss configuration between hostname and network name

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque yes, but how can this happen (what can be changed?) if one moment myQueue method works fine, and just after it @RabbitListener(queues = Q_INPUT) read fails?

Comment: That hostname are configured in the factory
   //setting other configs